# Is it possible to stay in the same server behind a round robin load balancer?

Tags: spring, spring-security, load-balancing

I have a Web App, with Spring Security, and it's behind a round robin load balancer, so whenever the load balancer jumps from server A to Server B the session  lost.

We don't want to use Remember-Me cookies, maybe is paranoia, but the data is too sensible.

And we can't configure the load balancer to have sticky sessions, (that's another department, and asking them to configure the load balancer to do this is our last option)

Is it possible to configure the xmls of Spring, to never go outside the server the user originally fell in?

So all the petitions the user make in server A always gonna be served by Server A ?

Comment: Isn't this what sticky sessions are meant to do? Spring can do nothing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have different URL's for each server:

- server A: www1.myapp.com
- server B: www2.myapp.com

Then when user goes to the app, they redirected to one of the above URL's.  This way they will be fixed on that server for future requests.

However, this will mean that if one server goes down, then the user will not be directed to the other server, so it would not be redundant.
You could get around this by having the server, that was still up, take over the other URL if the other server went down.

Here is the flow:

- user hits www.myapp.com
- loadbalancer send traffic to server A
- server A notices URL=www.myapp.com, so it redirects to www1.myapp.com
- user hits www1.myapp.com
- traffic hits server A (loadbalancer is bypassed)

If you dont want to expose the servers to the wWW, then you could setup extra pools on the LB as follows:

- www.myapp.com : server A, server B
- www1.myapp.com : server A
- www2.myapp.com : server B

Comment: That's what we were thinking but this is when it gets complicated (or really simple and silly), those servers A and B, are in another net, one that only the load balancer can access, so I am guessing there is no way that server A can redirect us to server B?

Comment: Well they can do http redirect (HTTP 302).  This would be done in your application code, or perhaps apache config.  The tricky part is making one server take over the from the other.

Comment: but... in order for the bypass to work, Server A and B should be visible outside their net right ?

Comment: yes, thats right.  Or you could setup 2 new pools on the loadbalancer, but then you will need more work done by the team that setup the LB.